# When sorting a table, is it faster to reorder the DOM elements or to rewrite the elements' data?

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom

Typically, when I sort a table in the DOM, I create a data array that mirrors the table elements, capturing the information that's meaningful to me (including any attributes that are relevant) in JS objects. At this point, after determining the proper sort, I have two choices:

1. Rewrite the data in the table (using innerHTML, textContent, etc.), iterating over all the  table elements.
2. Reorder the table row element (i.e. HTML nodes) to reflect the proper order in the sorted array.

Which method is less costly (i.e. faster)? I assume it's the latter, but I'm not sure. Can you explain why a particular method is faster?

Comment: This is usually a tough to predict because while the second obviosly should be faster, it however constantly crosses the JS/Native API boundary which is costly. The innerHTML
way however invokes expensive parser and a full rebuild of a tree, however, there is no boundary crossing during this (obviously you will build the whole string in JS before passing it and just setting innerHTML **once**).

Comment: benchmark? maybe? It probably depends on the browser too.

Comment: Try it: http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: By "*rewriting the data*" you mean "… of each `<td>` cell"?

Comment: Yes. I mean accessing the particular <td> HTML Element and doing a .textContent = "blah" on i.